How do I change Orthographic camera size smoothly?
I am trying to change my ortho size on cinemachine smoothly. I have it set up to zoom in and out on mouse wheel but it happens instantly and id like it to take a few seconds and do it smoothly. Like a slow zoom in and out. i cant seem to get it to work. i am using cinemachine for the camera and input actions to capture the zoom currently. and I have it set to a specific number because I want those to be the max zoom in and out values.
i know cinemachine has smooth pathing for changing waypoints instantly I'm hoping there is one for changing the zoom instantly as well or someone knows of a way to do this another way. what i want to make is like the zooming that final fantasy tactics has where you press the button and it slow zooms in to a set value and back out not manually keep scrolling/pressing a button over and over to finally get it to where you want it.
Something like slowly decreasing the float value may work. but that could take more time then I'd like. But i welcome any ideas on how to do this.
public class Zoom : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CinemachineVirtualCamera currentCamera;
    
     public void OnZoomIn(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {


     if (context.started == true)
    {
      currentCamera.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = 7.0f;
      
    }
  }

  public void OnZoomout(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.started == true)
    {
       currentCamera.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = 14.0f;
    }
  }
}

I have tried adding a speed value and tried using time.deltatime but ether I did it wrong or something because it just screwed the whole camera up and zoomed in or out to far and still happened instantly.

You will need to set desired state somewhere (for example property) and use Update to move toward target size.
public class Zoom : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CinemachineVirtualCamera currentCamera;
    public bool IsZoomDesired {get; private set; } // Are we zooming in?
   public float Speed = 7.0f; // In zoom units per seconds.

   // Added
   public void Update() 
   {
       var target = IsZoomDesired ? 7.0f : 14.0f;
      currentCamera.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = Mathf.MoveTowards(currentCamera.m_Lens.OrthographicSize, target, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
    
     public void OnZoomIn(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {


     if (context.started == true)
    {
       IsZoomDesired  = true;
      
    }
  }

  public void OnZoomout(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
  {
     if (context.started == true)
    {
        IsZoomDesired= false;
    }
  }
}


Thank you Very much. That worked perfectly and I see where I went wrong when trying to do this myself.

you could have two virtual cameras with different zoom settings then just turn on and off the camera with a higher priority. On the unity camera for the cinemachine brain set the blend type and duration.
simply just turn it on or off and no other code is needed
zoomedMachine.setActive(true);

you could also use distance and speed to figure out duration and set the brains duration to that so that you always get a constant speed. There are quite a few things you can do without having to use updates or lerps or movetowards or anything.
